# How to convert UTF-8 string to RTF string in java?

Tags: java, rtf

Currently my project need export report to MS Word , and i choose using RTFTemplate engine to do it. But my problem is I need convert all character to RTF string first . Everyone have experiment with this problem can suggest me ?

Comment: RTFTemplate can be found at https://rtftemplate.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368098/80901

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
You can use RtfDocument from iText:
new RtfDocument().filterSpecialChar(baos, sentence, true, true);

Answer (score -1):

[POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

is an apache project that help works with MS Office format.