# Replace word with word with umlaut in RTF and C#

Tags: c#, rtf, non-ascii-characters

I'm working with a RTF-template. In this template there are a few places where text need to be replaced. This works fine, when using ASCII chars. When I use non-ASCII chars, the chars changes to question marks.

My program code:

```
memo = memo.Replace("%TITEL%", titel);
```

memo is the RTF file, which is readed in my code as a string. `%TITEL%` exists in the RTF-template en `titel` has the following text:

```
Förderband
```

So `%TITEL%` is replaces by `Förderband`.

When I open the document, word shows:

```
F?rderband
```

I add the RTF-string to a Word document with the following:

```
// Read RTF document content.
                        string rtfDocumentContent = memo;

                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtfDocumentContent)))
                        {
                            chunk.FeedData(ms);
                        }

                        AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;

                        // Embed AltChunk after the last paragraph.
                        mainDocPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(
                          altChunk, mainDocPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How do you save the file?

Comment: What encoding does "the document" have?

Comment: What encoding are you using to write the file?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368020/how-to-output-unicode-string-to-rtf-using-c help?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368020/how-to-output-unicode-string-to-rtf-using-c A function is provided which changes UTF chars to their respective code point representations.

Comment: I've updated my question with the encoding part

Answer (score 0):

You are using ASCII encoding. Perhaps you should change to UTF-8 using the following code block

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtfDocumentContent)))
{
    chunk.FeedData(ms);
}
```

Hope this helps