# Eto.Forms StackLayout of Labels refreshing the whole list on Add

Tags: c#, eto

Here's a video of what's going on when I call `StackLayout.Items.Add(Label)` : https://streamable.com/hczt8

It seems that the list is entirely being emptied to a new list, and the simple code is that one :

```cs
    public class ChatPanel : Scrollable
    {
        StackLayout _messages;

        public ChatPanel()
        {
            _messages = new StackLayout();
            Content = _messages;
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Azure;

            _currentAccountData.Chat.EvOnChatMessage += OnMessage; // Custom event when a message is received
        }

        void OnMessage(ChatMessage m)
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            string date = $"[00:00:00]";
            if (m.GetType().Equals(typeof(PlayerMessage)))
            {
                PlayerMessage message = (PlayerMessage) m;
                label.Text = $"{date} {message.Pseudo}: {message.Message}";
            }
            else
            {
                label.Text = $"{date} {((ServerMessage)m).Message}";
            }
            _messages.Items.Add(new StackLayoutItem(label)); // I tried without "StackLayoutItem" too
        }
    }
```

I can't find any Container or Control fitting my needs. ([complete list here](http://api.etoforms.picoe.ca/html/N_Eto_Forms.htm))

Why does it refresh like that ? Is there another Control I can use to avoid this? Or am I misusing the component ?

Comment: I was doing it wrong because the `Add` method was not called from the UI thread. But still, it is extremely long when there are like 10 messages. I was planning to have like 1000 in the buffer so it's not going to happen right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label is not adapted to this.
I used `RichtextBox` and set `Rtf` property.
I had to make use of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368098/3679206)